# Font styles disappear when .svg is downloaded

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have an app, where you can dynamically create documents. Output of this document in the browser is in .svg format. Document is downloadable. But when I download it, all font styles disappear. It make sense, physical computer do not recognize it. My question. Is there any way to embed fonts to .svg using react.js, or somehow take a snapshot (in .png let's say) of the document so my fonts wouldn't disappear?

Comment: Yes. You can embed font files usint `@font-face` and data URLs.

Comment: How to do it using React? Because whatever I try, seems not working.